# Catching an event from an a class which inherits EventEmitter using es6 classes

Tags: javascript, node.js, events, ecmascript-6

I'm new to Javascript and es6. I am attempting to catch an event emitted by an object which is an ecmascript-6 (es6) class called LaserHandler,  that inherits EventEmitter. My listener is present in an object which is also an es6 class object called QRMarker, that instantiates the object. This is on nodejs not browser is used.

I expect to see the callback function of the of the listener to be called. The listener is not fired. There is no indication of error.

So I tried various alternate coding approaches including 1) using the 'event-emitter-es6' npm module. 2) rewriting to use *const* *events = require('events').EventEmitter* and extending events. 3) Varying the location of the listeners, emits, and where the class is instantiated.

The result of *console.log (qrMarker)*: In the following code is:

```
QRMarker {
  domain: null,
  _events:
   { stationId: [ [Function: listener], [Function] ],
     '*': [Function] },
  _eventsCount: 2,
  _maxListeners: undefined,
  id: undefined }


const EventEmitter = require('event-emitter-es6');
```

/*LaserHandler.js*/

```
let qrMarker;
module.exports = class LaserHandler extends EventEmitter {
    constructor(s, l) {
        super();
        logger = l;
        socket = s;
        qrMarker = new QRMaker(this.logger);
    }
    manageLaser() {
        qrMarker.communication(socket);
        socket.on ('LaserDown',  () => { 
        console.log('LaserHandler.manageLaser: received event' 
          )});
        qrMarker.on('stationId', (data) => {console.log(data)} );
        qrMarker.on('*', (data) => {console.log ('Caught event !!!')});
    }
}
/*end of file*/
/* QRMarker.js */
module.exports = class QRMarker extends EventEmitter {

constructor(l, id) {
    super();
    logger = l;
    this.id = id;
}
communication(s) {
    let connected = false;
    let socket = s;
    let dataBuffer;
    let lastStatusCode;

     this.emit( 'stationId', stationId);

     dataBuffer = Buffer.from(data);
            connected = true;
         }
      }
 }
/* end of file */
/* LaserService */

module.exports = class LaserService  {
    constructor () {    
    }

   startNeworking () {
       server = net.createServer();
       server.on('connection', function (socket) {
          let laserHandler = new LaserHandler(socket, logger); 
          laserHandler.manageLaser();
        });

    server.listen(41020, function () {});
   }
}
```

/*end of file */
/*TestLaserService -- this file is executed from node */

```
var LaserService = require("../LaserService.js");
let laserService  = new LaserService(2);
laserService.startNeworking();
```

/* end of file*/

Thank you.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Nothing in your code ever instantiates `LaserHandler` or calls calls `manageLaser` or `communication`, so event emitter or not, your code sample doesn't currently do anything. Please make a functional trimmed down example.

Comment: @loganfsmyth Thanks. I believe this is what you wanted.